# How to update a biblio field with Entity Metadata Wrapper?

Tags: 7, entities

I can update a field using Entity Metadata Wrapper (EMW). Here's how I can accomplish this.

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
$node_wrapper->field_custom_field='new value';
```

However, I'm not able to access and update biblio fields provided by biblio module in the same way. This code won't work

```
 $node_wrapper->some_biblio_field='new value';
```

How can I update biblio fields using EMW?

Comment: Drupal 7 does not have CCK. It will mislead others.

Comment: What is the module's version you are using?

Comment: I'm using version 7.x-1.0-rc7 which is currently the latest version. and you are right CCK is misleading, so I removed that part. I actually meant the field API.

Comment: IMPO, the design of 1.x version of this module is really bad. I found that they had a 3.x version on [Github](https://github.com/Gizra/biblio). If it is a new project. It's worth to try.

Comment: @ Jimmy, It is a very useful module and I have used it in several projects. They should start implementing it for Drupal 8 and not focus much on Drupal 7.

Comment: @AdminS It's time to make one and contribute to community. LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Bibliography module](https://www.drupal.org/project/biblio) isn't using D7's [field API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/group/field/7.x). It's misleading since the module's manage fields UI (**/admin/structure/types/manage/biblio/fields**) does make it appear as if it's using the field API; however it installs its [own database schema](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/biblio/tree/biblio.install?h=7.x-1.0-rc7#n354) for storing data for Bibliography nodes.

As such, [Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity)'s EMW isn't much help in your case.

Comment: I had the same feeling, just wanted to make sure that this is the case. Thank you for the clarification.